# Composer custom repositories local AND remote

Tags: composer-php, build-tools

We are using custom repositories that are not held on Packagist, and thus need to use composer's "repositories" key:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/name/repo"
},
```

However we also want to develop these locally before pushing them to GitHub

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "/path/to/repo"
},
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/name/repo"
}
```

However if a new user downloads the repo and just wants to use from GitHub (maybe they won't be developing locally) they get a big red error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   No driver found to handle VCS repository /path/to/dir

Is there a way that composer can tolerate this and just move down to the next line where it will find the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That this is possible right now, as far as I know. The defined "/path/to/dir" needs to exist, it needs to be a repo and the repo needs to contain a composer.json file, otherwise Composer will fail.

Sounds like a valid point for a PR to ignore an invalid repository definition but not sure what Jordie thinks of this ;)

As an alternative: You could set-up your own Satis repo and pull the package from there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've found the offending code in the repository so may try fork and PR.